# [cURL/PHP] Login with Google Account

Tags: php, logging, curl, authentication

I'm writing a script which is connected with my google account. But I have problems at the beginning of this. Google blocks my logging. I receive this error:

> Your browser's cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on.

Here you have a script:

```
<?php
$email = "login";
$password = "pass";

//curl get
function curl_get( $curl, $url, $cookiefile) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    return $data;
}

//curl post

function curl_post( $curl, $url, $cookiefile, $post) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    return $data;
}

//cookie file
$cookiefile = "cookie.txt";

$curl = curl_init( );

//get url to grab GALX & dsh to login
$data = curl_get( $curl, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?uilel=3&service=youtube&passive=true&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252Findex&hl=en_US&ltmpl=sso", $cookiefile);


preg_match('/name="GALX"\s*value="(.*?)"/', $data, $galx);

preg_match('/name="dsh" id="dsh"\s*value="(.*?)"/', $data, $dsh);


//login
$data = curl_post( $curl, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth", $cookiefile, "ltmpl=sso&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252Findex&service=youtube&uilel=3&dsh=$dsh[1]&ltmpl=sso&hl=en_US&ltmpl=sso&timeStmp=&secTok=&GALX=$galx[1]&Email=$email&Passwd=$password&PersistentCookie=yes&rmShown=1&signIn=Sign+in&asts=");

//auth url
$data = curl_get( $curl, "https://www.google.com/accounts/CheckCookie?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252Findex&hl=en_US&service=youtube&ltmpl=sso&chtml=LoginDoneHtml", $cookiefile);
echo $data;
?>
```

Cookie file is fine, problem is probably somewhere else.

Thank you in advance for help.
Mikolaj.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OAuth to login with your Google account.

Here's a PHP OAuth library: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/ and project's wiki How To page with sample code: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo